# How to do a performance Testing with MS Botframework

Tags: botframework

We have created a bot which uses Luis to address user queries. Would like to understand how can we perform a performance testing to my bot which can be like a VSTS testing. Yes tried with VSTS also but of no use, since my bot api is always sending a request and response couldn't capture the exact one. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are using Azure bot service directly or the other way. Considering if you are using the Azure Bot Service following are the steps to configure performance test.

You can do performance test using Azure Bot Service from continuous integration tab

[image: configure]

Select the team services account, subscription and location.

[image: enter details]

You can track the build and errors using Azure App insights

[image: app insights]

Let me know if you are looking for anything else.

Regards

-Jyo