# Using BotFramework-Emulator for load testing

Tags: c#, botframework

currently BotFramework-Emulator can be used as 1 client to test the bot. I wonder can it be used/extended to emulate 10000 clients for load testing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a performance Testing with MS Botframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835206/how-to-do-a-performance-testing-with-ms-botframework)

Answer (score 4):

A few days ago the BotFramework team published a [blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/Load-Testing-A-Bot/)  with some guidance around how to load test a bot.

I recommend you to go through it to understand all the pieces and what you would have to build to effectively load test your bot.

Comment: Yeah I read about it. However with my current knowledge I dont know how to actual implement the test into my bot tho. If you can brief me a few steps toward the issue i would be very appreciated